# VBA - close non-excel file

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a question I am unable to find the answer to. I have a macro that imports data from a .MHTML file into my worksheet (Using the .MHTML file is my only option unfortunately. It is an export from SAP and opens in Excel but is not recognized as an Excel file due to file extension type.). At the end of the macro I wouuld like to close it. It is not recognized as an excel workbook so I am unable to use the simple: `Workbooks().close` command.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try this link: http://www.taltech.com/support/entry/opening_and_closing_an_application_from_vba

Comment: Thanks Limak, I think with the correct modification, it could work. From the example, I changed `strTerminateThis = "bc-wedge.exe"` to `strTerminateThis = "SAP_export.MHTML"`.   I think if I were to change it to `strTerminateThis = "EXCEL.exe *32"`, it would work but it would also terminate my macro since it is also under EXCEL.exe *32 process. Do you know how to modify the code to look through the open Applications instead of just the open Processes? Thanks

Comment: Why you want to terminate `"EXCEL.exe *32"` process? Maybe you can provide me some screenshot form Windows Task Manager to make me understand your concern.

Comment: In Windows Task Manager > Processes I currently have two Image Names with "EXCEL.EXE". One is for my macro and the other is for the .MHTML export that I am trying to close. The link you sent me seems like it terminates the process you define with `strTerminateThis = ""` so I first tried "SAP_export.MHTML" which is the name of the export I'd like to close. The code does not error but it doesn't do anything because there is nothing in the Processes tab with that Image Name. I would have to use "EXCEL.EXE" but when I tried this is just terminated my macro. So If there is a way to distinguish..

Comment: Go to Task Manager > Details and see if the task you are looking for is for sure named `SAP_export.MHTML` .

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure how to get a screenshot on here...  But yes, WTM > Applications tab shows the task as "Microsoft Excel - SAP_export.MHTML" and for WTM > Processes tab it shows as "EXCEL.EXE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find this code and after changing the Caption to match what is shown in Task Manager, it worked: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?208430-Use-sendmessage-to-close-an-application

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

Sub ExportClose()
Dim CloseIt As Long
CloseIt = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Microsoft Excel - SAP_export.MHTML")
PostMessage CloseIt, WM_CLOSE, CLng(0), CLng(0)
End Sub
```

Note: This works great for my system but not for my colleague
.. Currently trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try just:

```
Windows("SAP_export.MHTML").Close
```

Comment: I was unable to get that to work, Limak but thanks for the help. I was able to find a way using API